# generate a list of strings using for loop

Tags: python

I am new to python. I want to generate a list like below:

```
df_col = ['h1b', 'h2b', 'h3b', 'h4b', 'h5b', 'h6b', 'h7b', ... ,'h100b']
```

my way of doing it now is

```
df_col = [''.join('h' & i & 'b') for i in range(1, 101)]
```

but it is not working. Anyone suggestion? thanks.

Comment: The operator for string concatenation is `+`. You need to convert the int to a string before you can concatenate it. Try `df_col = ['h' + str(i) + 'b' for i in range(1, 101)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join()` works on a list, so provide `'h'`, `i` and `'b'` as a list.

Since `join()` does not like integers between string, don't forget to parse `i` to a string using `str()`:

```
df_col = [ ''.join([ 'h', str(i), 'b' ]) for i in range(1, 101) ]
```

---

Since you're joining with an empty string, consider using an [f string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals):

```
df_col = [ f"h{i}b" for i in range(1, 101) ]
```

Comment: If you want add the string format documentation ([official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals)). BTW, +1 because you explained the problem

Comment: Mmm thanks, I guess I copied the wrong link on google ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension and map each index in the range to an f-string.

```py
df_col = list(f"h{n}b" for n in range(1, 101))
```

If you are not going to need all the values right away, you should consider a generator. It has a much smaller memory footprint.

Note the difference between the `()` (parenthesis) and `[]` (square brackets).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(format='[%(levelname)s] %(asctime)s %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

# Generator
df_col = (f"h{n}b" for n in range(1, 101))
logging.debug(', '.join(x for x in df_col))
logging.info(f"Size of generator: {sys.getsizeof(df_col)} bytes") # 128 bytes

# List
df_col = [f"h{n}b" for n in range(1, 101)]
logging.debug(', '.join(x for x in df_col))
logging.info(f"Size of list: {sys.getsizeof(df_col)} bytes") # 920 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `map` function with a `lambda` function:

```
df_col = list(map(lambda i: f'h{i}b', range(1, 101)))
```